# "document" in mozilla extension js modules?

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, javascript

I am building Firefox extension, that creates single XMPP chat connection, that can be accessed from all tabs and windows, so I figured, that only way to to this, is to create connection in javascript module and include it on every browser window. Correct me if I am wrong...

EDIT: I am building traditional extension with xul overlays, not using sdk, and talking about those modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules

So I copied Strophe.js into js module. Strophe.js uses code like this:

```
/*_Private_ function that creates a dummy XML DOM document to serve as
 *  an element and text node generator.
 */
```

[---]

```
if (document.implementation.createDocument === undefined) {
    doc = this._getIEXmlDom();
    doc.appendChild(doc.createElement('strophe'));
} else {
    doc = document.implementation
        .createDocument('jabber:client', 'strophe', null);
}
```

and later uses doc.createElement() to create xml(or html?) nodes.

All worked fine, but in module I got error "Error: ReferenceError: document is not defined".
How to get around this?

(Larger piece of exact code: http://pastebin.com/R64gYiKC )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [hiddenDOMwindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIAppShellService#Attributes)

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var doc = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.document;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not be correctly attaching your content script to the worker page.  Make sure that you're using something like tabs.attach() to attach one or more content scripts to the worker page (see documentation [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html)).

Otherwise you may need to wait for the DOM to load, waiting for the entire page to load

```
window.onload = function ()
{
Javascript code goes here
}
```

Should take at least diagnose that issue (even if the above isn't the best method to use in production).  But if I had to wager, I'd say that you're not attaching the content script.

Comment: I am not usind SDK, but instead making traditional extension with xul overlays.